# DragEventArgs.GetPosition always .12?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, wpf-controls

I have a strange behavior of a "Point"-object. 
I use a Drag'n'Drop and on the drop I catch the `DragEventArgs` as the simple variable `'e'`. Later I call this line:

```
Point mc = e.GetPosition(ShelfGrid);
```

And that leads to a nearly correct result. The `mc.X` is always `.0`, if `3.0` or `287.0` or `699.0`, but the `mc.Y` is always `.12`. So the results from the `mc.X` taken would seem like `3.12`, `287.12` and `699.12`.
Now my question: "Why?"
There has to be a reason for the `.12`, hasn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, that's the Y position of your debugging code line. Having different X values means you scroll the debug code line up and down. Just write the point values to output window instead of debug points and see.